# Failure delivering result ResultInfo{who=null, request=1, result=-1, data=Intent..)

Tags: android, android-intent, android-camera

I need litle help. I have Context menu from which user can choose how to take an image, from gallery or from camera, but when I select image from gallery or take image with camera and click on OK, I get this error.

Here you can take a look at this error: [HERE](http://pastebin.com/4VNsib68)

Here  you can take a look at whole my code: [[HERE]](http://pastebin.com/v478SiUR)

Answer (score 0):

The view that you have set for the whole activity using setContentView does not contain R.id.ivCar1.

All you have done is added a few views to the animator. You will have to do setcontentview  with the layout which contains ivCar1 Otherwise ivCar1 will be null which is giving you the exception